# Logging not getting disabled

Tags: redhat, logging, tomcat, java, log4j

Out **Tomcat 8** is logging so much so that by the evening the **catalina.out** inflates to **GBs of data**. I followed the **procedure given on the tomcat website to replace JULI logging with LOG4J**. Now LOG4J has started logging in catalina but **catalina.out is still being logged in** as earlier. We are using **Java 7 over Redhat 5**. I have also commented everything out in the JRE logging properties file as well. Please advise.

Comment: LOG4J vs JULI logging has nothing to do with your issue. The only reason to switch logging framework in this case would be if you cannot figure out how to configure JULI logging as opposed to configuring LOG4J ... but that would be treating the symptom and not he cause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in conf/logging.properties the property org.apache.catalina.level to log level you want to have.

Comment: That was not affecting the size of the logs. Than, to switch to log4j from juli, I followed the instructions on the Tomcat website and deleted the conf/logging.properties file altogether. But the logging still hasn't stopped.

Comment: @6nagi9: It's not the JRE's `logging.properties` you need to change, it is that of Tomcat which you'll find in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`, alternatively one of the webapps on that Tomcat may have its own logging properties and in that case it will (typically) be in `.../webapps/<appname>/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` file.

Comment: there isn't any webapps logging properties file and i have commented out both catalina as well as jre logging properties files.